# How do I override the vocabulary template but only on a specific content type

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary called "Sectors" and a content type called "News". Basically the vocab displays which sector the blog article is related to and links to the corresponding CMS page about that sector.

How do I customise the template that shows that vocabulary on my pages of that content type?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make that with [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) :)

You have to create your views with the fields  you need. After that you will be able to theme them globally and locally.
check [views's theme suggestion](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7.x-3.x)

i hope it helped you